# Data Modeling for finding existing contacts on a mobile app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, data-modeling

I'm working on an iPhone app where I need to alert the user when a person on the addressbook joins the service. I'm using rails as backend and currently have phone number as an attribute under User.

So far my idea was to:

1. When a user signs up for the app, access addressbook and send it to the server (with consent)
2. Have a separate "Phone" model which has only one attribute "number" of string type
3. Have another Association model "PhoneAssociation" which belongs_to Phone via self referential join
4. Query this table whenever a new user joins and notify the relevant party.

But I wanted to make sure this is how it's supposed to be implemented. Are there better ways to do this? Thank you.

EDIT: To clarify, I am curious about if this is the right way to data model "Find Friends" feature> Above solution was just something I came up with but I thought there could be other ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using the PhoneAssociation model as a join object from Phone to Phone. In this case, since you don't seem to need much other than the join, you should use the has_and_belongs_to_many association, detailed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), in section 2.6. With this association, you wouldn't need to explicitly create the PhoneAssociation model you would only need Phone.

Comment: Thank you, and I agree it's a good idea to use has_and_belongs_to_many like you pointed out. However the main thing I was curious about was whether this is the right way to data model "Find friends" feature. Maybe it's better to do it without creating a separate "Phone" table, etc.

Comment: Well,if it makes sense in your context, I'd consider folding this into the user model. However, I think it's a good design to have the phone model because it encapsulates the idea you're trying to implement without complicating the user model. It's a clean, modular design.